# On whom are the aliens-turned-music stars in Interstella 5555 based?

Tags: reference, interstella-5555

In the movie *Interstella 5555* by Daft Punk it is insinuated that all genius musicians on Earth are actually aliens kidnapped by an evil manager and turned into humans. Some of them are shown being transformed. The first one is shown as a kid playing piano in a baroque setting, so I am seeing a clear indication that this is supposed to be Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart. On whom are the rest based?

[image: Young mozart-like person]
**#1 This one I got the reference as Mozart.**

[image: second person]
**#2 This one is later shown with a trumpet.**

[image: third musician]
**#3 This one is later shown with a grand piano.**

[image: fourth musician]
**#4 This one is later shown with a classical or an acoustic guitar**

[image: fifth musician]
**#5 This one is later shown with a broken electric guitar.**

Answer (score 2):

[TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/Interstella5555) suggests

> Before the Crescendolls, Earl de Darkwood's previous victims were famous musicians who look an awful lot like Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart, Jimi Hendrix, Ella Fitzgerald, Janis Joplin and Jimmy Page.

Hendrix

[image]

It should be noted that Hendrix was not a trumpet player so I'm suspecting TV Tropes might have this wrong.

In place I offer

**Miles Davis**

[image]

Ella Fitzgerald

[image]

Janis Joplin

[image]

Jimmy Page

[image]

Comment: Hendrix with a trumpet? He also doesn't seem to quite look the same. Not sure I'm entirely buying TVTropes here. The rest look somewhat reasonable.

Comment: I'd have gone for Nina Simone as the pianist. I didn't even know Ella played. Nina was a consummate pianist. The long-haired delicately-framed blonde with a fringe I'd have thought much more Joni Mitchell than Janis Joplin. Joplin was no shrinking violet.

Comment: I'm slightly bothered by Miles Davis with a beard [though I'm just as sure as everyone else that Hendrix was no horn player;) but I can't think of a suitable alternative.

Comment: I would accept this answer but I see some small discussion here in the comments, so I will wait for a while to see if any more revelations come up